# how to set custom json response structure in Go

Tags: json, go

I am importing *"encoding/json"* package to print output in *json*.I was able to get the json format but i want to modify the response structure.
Here is the sample code

```
var people []Person
people = append(people, Person{Id: "1", Firstname: "John", Lastname: "Doe", Address: Address{City: "City X", State: "State X"}})
people = append(people, Person{Id: "2", Firstname: "Koko", Lastname: "Doe", Address: Address{City: "City Z", State: "State Y"}})
people = append(people, Person{Id: "3", Firstname: "Francis", Lastname: "Sunday"})
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(people)
```

which outputs the following response

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "address": {
        "city": "City X",
        "state": "State X"
    }
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "firstname": "Koko",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "address": {
        "city": "City Z",
        "state": "State Y"
    }
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "firstname": "Francis",
    "lastname": "Sunday",
    "address": {
        "city": "",
        "state": ""
    }
}
]
```

But i want to response into the following format

```
{
"status": "200",
"data": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "address": {
            "city": "City X",
            "state": "State X"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "firstname": "Koko",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "address": {
            "city": "City Z",
            "state": "State Y"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "firstname": "Francis",
        "lastname": "Sunday",
        "address": {
            "city": "",
            "state": ""
        }
    }
        ]
}
```

How can I modify the response format ? I am beginner in Go. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What did you try? What doesn't work for you?

Comment: I want to reorganize json response format.Since i am new in go i was not able to reformat and sadly I was not able to found in internet .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to change structure of your response, you need to provide the structure that you want to achieve with type.

You can define `Response` struct type which will consist of `data` and `status` fields:

```
type Response struct {
    Status string `json:"status"`
    Data []Person `json:"data"`
}

var people []Person
people = append(people, Person{Id: "1", Firstname: "John", Lastname: "Doe", Address: Address{City: "City X", State: "State X"}})
people = append(people, Person{Id: "2", Firstname: "Koko", Lastname: "Doe", Address: Address{City: "City Z", State: "State Y"}})
people = append(people, Person{Id: "3", Firstname: "Francis", Lastname: "Sunday"})
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

resp := Response{Status: "200", Data: people}
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(resp)
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to pass response and request object to the function you are using `w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")`. Either you can append to the struct or you can initialize it with multiple values in an array.

```
package main

import "encoding/json"

//  Data struct
type Data struct {
    status string
    data   []Person
}

// Person struct
type Person struct {
    Id        string
    Firstname string
    Lastname  string
    Address   Address
}

// Address struct
type Address struct {
    City  string
    State string
}

func main() {
    people := Data{
        status: "200",
        data: []Person{
            {Id: "1", Firstname: "John", Lastname: "Doe", Address: Address{City: "City X", State: "State X"}},
            {Id: "2", Firstname: "Koko", Lastname: "Doe", Address: Address{City: "City Z", State: "State Y"}},
            {Id: "3", Firstname: "Francis", Lastname: "Sunday", Address: Address{City: "City Z", State: "State Y"}},
        },
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(people)
}
```

Comment: This is also another  best solution for my problem.